# Subtitle Problem with a Vogue Paris video on YouTube

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm trying to transcribe the french subtitle cuz the video only contains English subtitle. Here's the link: [Adèle Farine, Vogue Paris](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bfv_G3SLmI&list=PLVRtRwc2n-r6ToS9OapZq9OilGU3zqrbi&index=15&t=0s)

I have some problem with some words she said in the video. Reasons are:

1. Hard to distinguish the words
2. Word usage

> 13
>   00:00:28,590 --> 00:00:30,720
>   qu'on en fait exactement, mais je pense
>
> 14
>   00:00:30,720 --> 00:00:31,949
>   qu'on va les dessiner en plein de choses,

---

> 16
>   00:00:35,489 --> 00:00:38,640
>   Je n’achète pas
>
> 17
>   00:00:38,640 --> 00:00:41,160
>   tant que ça de marque, je fais Ouen
>
> 18
>   00:00:41,160 --> 00:00:43,200
>   fripes, je chaîne beaucoup, mais j'ai

---

> 31
>   00:01:11,490 --> 00:01:12,780
>   le temps. C'est ça qui me rassure plus
>
> 32
>   00:01:12,780 --> 00:01:14,520
>   enfants vêtements en fait. J'aimerais
>
> 33
>   00:01:14,520 --> 00:01:17,640
>   bien être longue brûne, aux yeux

---

As you can see,

1. in the <13><14> bar, there's a word "dessiner", which should be a verb. But what I heard before it is "les" that's to be before a noun. I don't get it. Maybe she speaks too vaguely for me.
2. in the <16> to <18> bar, there's a sentence "je fais Ouen fripes...", of which I can't, absolutely, tell what she was saying. The same applies to "je chaîne beaucoup", which is too strange. I've searched on Google, and on vogue.fr, but nothing returned is informative.
3. The same as in [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bfv_G3SLmI&list=PLVRtRwc2n-r6ToS9OapZq9OilGU3zqrbi&index=15&t=0s), "plus enfant vêtements".. I don't have any clue as to what that means. As well as the "longue brûne".. The English subs says it's a "tall brunette", but the "longue" is bizarre in French word usage to describe "tall".

I would humbly thank anyone who could help me with this video, native speakers or non-native, as long as you could provide me with some information that's useful for me to finish this subtitle.
Timestamps are in the bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She doesn't speak vaguely but here and there she repeats a word that shouldn't be there or temporises with an "euh"; this is the sort of thing that impinges normally in people's speech. What is spurious in her speech is in upper case letters.

**I** Je dessines des poissons parce que je fais une collab …

… qu'on en fait exactement mais je pense qu'on va les décliner en plein de choses ASSEZ assez drôles, des vêtements, EUH, TUDU, des objets, trucs comme ça. TEUH J'achète pas tant que ça de marques,  J'FAIS, ou en fripes, je chine beaucoup, mais

… et moi j'ai besoin de vêtements que  QUE j'ai porté souvent et QUE dans lesquels, je sais pas, comme si je pouvais me voir dedans et savoir exactement à quoi je ressemblais tout le temps, c'est ça qui me rassure le plus dans un vêtement en fait. J'AIMERAIS BIEN J'aimerais bien être une longue , brune, aux yeux très fonçés …

1. The verb "chaîner" is in fact "chiner".

   - Chercher des occasions chez les brocanteurs, les chiffonniers, etc. (chineur). https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=chiner+def
2. She does say "une longue, brune" and there is no doubt that this corresponds to "tall brunette"; you are correct, this is not standard French.

Comment: My gratitude to you LPH, your answer really shed light. This video has been haunting me for over a week till now. As for the "chaîner" turned out to be "chiner", I guess I still need to improve on listening skills. Thanks again, humbly.

Comment: @HewieGlaire You welcome ! If something remains uncertain don't hesitate asking again; there is no garantee that I'll find the answer, as even the French themselves, when it comes to real speech, aren't always able to make out what is being said, but again, I just might.

Comment: Absolutely! I guess this happens to everyone in any given country, human speech is indeed an abyss called 'sloth' into which we all plunge. And you sure might! You're a really wonderful contributor.